# Python recursive function wont change list defined in main()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here I wrote a recursive function to find the permutation of a list.

```
def backtrack(arr,tmp):
   if len(tmp)==len(arr):
       res.append(tmp)
       #==print res here==
       print(res)
   else:
       for i in range(len(arr)):
           if arr[i] in tmp: continue
           tmp.append(arr[i])
           backtrack(arr,tmp)
           tmp.pop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   points=[1,2,3]
   res=[]
   tmp=[]
   backtrack(points,tmp)
   print(res)
   #code result
   #[[1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2]]
   #[[2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 3]]
   #[[2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]
   #[[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
   #[[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
   #[[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

I have no idea why the list 'res' defined in main() wont be updated when we pass it to a recursive function. Any suggestion about how to update 'res'?

Comment: But it is being changed.  It goes from being empty to having six items in it.  Each of those items is an empty list because they're all actually the same item: the list `tmp`, which you've `pop`ped all the items out of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: The `res` variable you define inside your recursive function is not the same as the one defined in main.

Comment: @toti08 since `res` is NOT defined in `backtrack()` it _is_ the global one.

Comment: Just for the sake of correctness: you say (about `res`) " when we pass it to a recursive function",  but you are NOT passing it anywhere, you're relying on a global (which is plain evil BTW).

Comment: Also, you may want to learn the proper use of `for` loops in Python - you don't need this `range(len(arr))` nor `arr[i]`, you can get the items directly ie `for item in ["a", "b", "c"]: print(item)`

Comment: And finally: read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
res.append(tmp)
```

you are appending to the global list `res` a reference to the list `tmp`. Any future changes to `tmp` will be visible through `res` as it just contains multiple references to the same `tmp` list.

Instead you probably want to append a copy of `tmp`:

```
res.append(list(tmp))
```

Make that change and your output is now:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Alternatively you could convert the `tmp` list into a `tuple`:

```
res.append(tuple(tmp))
```

If you do that the option is then identical to the output returned by `itertools.permutations`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3]))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```